# Django query with join?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Campaign(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name="campaigns")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

How can I select all contacts that have campaign name='CampaignName' in Campaign table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Contact.objects.filter(campaign__name='CampaignName')
```

Comment: Yes, there should be related_name, so campaigns_name is correct.